# jquery class toggle not closing previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="t1">
   head 1
</div>
<div class="t2">
    hi
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="t1">
head 2
</div>
<div class="t2">
    hi2
</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".t2").hide();
$(".t1").click(function(){
$(this).next(".t2").toggle();
});
```

I pressed first t1 then t2 is opening and when i press second t1,first t2 should close but it is still open

http://jsfiddle.net/q539mqon/3/

Comment: see the answer below that someone commented below..that is wat i expected..

Comment: Ok, I see what you were saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hide it in the click handler

```
var $t2s = $(".t2").hide();
$(".t1").click(function () {
    var $t2 = $(this).next(".t2").toggle();
    $t2s.not($t2).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dnLe56ko/)